# Is there any sample about using OpenFire's Plugins through Jabber.net Library in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xmpp, openfire, instant-messaging

I am working on C#-WPF project about IM. after some googling I Found One of the best choices to do this is Jabber/XMPP protocol so I install OpenFire as Jabber server and write a simple client application in C# by Jabber.net library. Now I want to use Kraken IM Gateway (One Of the OpenFire's Plugin) in my client application, But How?

Comment: Have you checked the readme? http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/kraken/readme.html

Comment: You may also want to consider Spectrum instead of Kraken -http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/46580